# Protractor - How to assert a value is not in the table?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I am writing a protractor test where I delete a record and need to assert that it is not in the table. How do I do it? To assert that a value is in the table I use the below code.

```
expect(by.cssContainingText('table tbody tr td' , 'test@example.com'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is expect not be present

```
expect(element(by.cssContainingText('table tbody tr td' , 'test@example.com')).isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
```

Better way is to wait until **invisibilityOf** element and then assert.

```
    const expected = require('protractor').ExpectedConditions
    const btn = element(by.cssContainingText('table tbody tr td' , 'test@example.com'))
    await browser.wait(expected.invisibilityOf(btn), 5000)
    expect(btn.isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
```

Use expected conditions to wait until invisibilityOf web element.

invisibilityOf(elementFinder: ElementFinder): Function;
(method) ProtractorExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(elementFinder: ElementFinder): Function
An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM. This is the opposite of 'visibilityOf'.

@example

```
let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be no longer visible on the dom.
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf($('#abc')), 5000);
@alias — ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf
```

@param elementFinder — The element to check

@returns
An expected condition that returns a promise representing whether the element is invisible.